# How to send push notification from a PWA on chrome for android with Google FCM and Microsoft azure as a hosting server

Tags: azure, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, azure-notificationhub

I've developed a PWA application and hosted in azure, I want to know how to send push notifications on my PWA with Google FCM using azure push notification hub. I have few questions like how to broadcast or send push notifications for a particular set of devices. How can I save the device end points in azure. I've gone through considerable amount of resources but couldn't get the proper flow. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following getting started document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-chrome-push-notifications-get-started

You can also find the example here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/PushToChromeApps